Obvious wrongness of Aristotle
Why did nobody notice the empirical wrongness of Aristotle's physics in the parts where possible in his time? It was held, for example, that a flying spear moves strongly horizontally and then falls strongly vertically. Hadn't anyone witnessed the flying and falling of a spear?

See this psot for a similar issue (and regarding the "obvious" vs not so obvious...)

Aristotle's wrongness was not so obvious to people without videocameras and slow motion:"Bowmen were well aware that they could shoot straight at a
target for maximum accuracy or fire into the air for maximum range. Those under a hail of arrows would have noted that they came from above and, under the circumstances, no one would have bothered to measure the exact angle of incidence." Hannam, Physics of war, see Walley, Aristotle, projectiles and guns.

The Unexplainable podcast has an episode which touches on the theme of weird beliefs held by past scientists. https://player.fm/series/unexplainable-2890259/does-garlic-break-magnets (the show's home page is at https://www.vox.com/unexplainable but I can't find the episode there!?)

Perhaps a better example might be: In Discourses on Two New Sciences Galileo cites Aristotle as claiming that objects fall at speeds proportional to their weights. (Not merely that heavier objects fall faster.) Salviati (the book's stand-in For Galileo) points out that if this were true then a 100-pound cannonball dropped from a 100-foot-high tower, at the same time as a stone, would hit the ground before the stone had fallen one foot.  Even Simplicio,Galileo's Aristotle fanboy punching bag, declines to defend this absurdity.



Aristotle maintained that women have fewer teeth than men; although he was twice married, it never occurred to him to verify this statement by examining his wives’ mouths. He said also that children will be healthier if conceived when the wind is in the north. One gathers that the two Mrs Aristotles both had to run out and look at the weathercock every evening before going to bed. He states that a man bitten by a mad dog will not go mad, but any other animal will (Hist. An., 704a); that the bite of the shrewmouse is dangerous to horses, especially if the mouse is pregnant (ibid., 604b); that elephants suffering from insomnia can be cured by rubbing their shoulders with salt, olive-oil, and warm water (ibid., 605a); and so on and so on. Nevertheless, classical dons, who have never observed any animal except the cat and the dog, continue to praise Aristotle for his fidelity to observation.

-- Bertrand Russell, The Impact of Science on Society
It's a lesson in trust in authority and received wisdom. It doesn't matter how prestigious someone may be. They may still be wrong, and we should check their work, and there is an unfortunate human tendency not to do so, for fear of being labeled a contrarian.
By uncritically agreeing with what someone prestigious said, we seem prestigious ourselves, and ingratiate ourselves into the community of other people doing the same.
The cure is to embrace empirical observation, to test propositions in impersonal, objective ways, and to rely on what makes sense to your individual sense of reason as opposed to saying what would gain you acceptance and prestige in a community.
Not a very popular cure, even today.

@IoannisPaizis, it would be nice when leaving comments even citations to include a translation in the language of this website.

@Kvothe, fair enough; it's the first time I do this; I consider philosophy as a multidimensional approach towards the meaning of life: some things unfortunately are restricted to those who are willing to find by themselves.

Ioannis's comment run through google translate since they don't care enough to make the content readable: "...obviously, such a situation, in which resolution is always governed, is not a democracy above all, because it is not capable of resolution at all. The things of democracy, because I divide this way..."

Indeed. Aristotle was exiled from Athens, & Socrates executed, for the questioning they did. Saying they didn't do enough ignores the constraints of their times, & the progress they made.

The trajectory in that picture isn't entirely wrong: a cannonball fired at a steep angle in an atmosphere will follow a trajectory closer to triangular than to the classic parabola.

... although there is unfortunately also a tendency these days to distrust authority too much, commonly in favour of trusting a different, far less reputable, less educated, less reliable and/or more biased, authority, or other similarly-unreliable sources. There is some balance to be found between recognising that everyone is wrong sometimes and that blind trust is dangerous, and also recognising that years of formal education and decades of professional experience tends to make people more likely to have correct ideas about a topic compared to someone with none of that.

@NotThatGuy As you say, such people aren't thinking critically or conducting empirical investigations, they're just trading one authority for another, less reliable one - the new authority being less interested in empirical, impersonal investigation. It's still the same mentality of over-trust in authority and insufficient reliance on empiricism. The new authority is selected for social and political reasons rather than scientific ones.

Nevertheless, +1 for the hilarious quote in the answer. suffering from insomnia can be cured by rubbing their shoulders with salt, olive-oil, and warm water I'm definitely up for that to cure my insomnia, depending on who does the rubbing.

@AnoE Apparently only works if you are an elephant...

In my humble opinion, Aristotle has been unfairly attacked in introductory science textbooks as a representative of dogma and careless unfounded beliefs. This is the probable reason for your hunch that most of his ideas were "obviously wrong".
As the great Carlo Rovelli says:

Aristotelian physics is a correct and non-intuitive approximation of
Newtonian physics in the suitable domain (motion in fluids), in the
same technical sense in which Newton theory is an approximation of
Einstein's theory. Aristotelian physics lasted long not because it
became dogma, but because it is a very good empirically grounded
theory.

Since your question is mainly about motion, please allow me to quote relevant information that I have mentioned in another question:

Aristotle (384 BC – 322 BC), a pioneering, iconoclastic, and brilliant
ancient Greek philosopher, made the observation in his writings that
the long term stable state of objects is at rest, that motion needs a
cause to make it happen, and that continuous motion needs a continuous
cause. He further observed that the cause should itself be in motion
for it to induce motion: a stationary object cannot induce another to
move.
He extended this line of deduction further by arguing that since all
observed motion in nature is required to be induced by a cause which
itself is in motion, there must be a primordial "unmoved mover"
which must be the seed cause behind all the subsequent motion. He drew
parallels between the concept of the unmoved mover, "active
intellect", and God.
There is absolutely nothing wrong in these observations for almost all
of the terrestrial motion experienced by humans, except the motion of
falling objects which seems to be caused by an unmoving Earth, and the
motion of living things which seem to move of their own will without
being caused by another moving object.

Even for these outliers, Aristotle developed elaborate ideas to explain their motion.
Regarding the motion of spear which you have quoted, the answer of Ioannis Paizis beautifully explains the nuance in Aristotle's philosophy (special thanks to them for actual quotes).
Further Reading: Aristotle's Physics: a Physicist's Look

Thank you Ritesh. It's very easy to get wiser than our predecessors.  It's harder to go back into their time and honestly evaluate whether we could have done better than them.

Note also that  from the perspective of thermodynamics, the idea that nothing moves continually without a cause is closer to the truth than Newton's laws. Every process transforms some of its (e.g. kinetic) energy into heat; everything (including stars etc.) slows down over time unless there is a force propelling it. That entropy increases over time is a central tenet of modern physics, having implications for black holes, cosmology etc. Newtonian physics are an (of course insightful) idealization missing a crucial part of actual reality.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica care to elaborate on that? Afaik conservation of momentum is pretty well defined and very much valid in every modern field of physics, barring those that are too esoteric for our universe. This doesn't invalidate the increasing entropy of the universe

@Gallifreyan Did you just sign up to make that comment? ;-) -- Of course conservation of momentum is well defined -- but momentum is conserved only for the overall system! And the overall system, at the end, is the entire universe. Any subsystem moving faster than average does slow down over time until everything is uniformly distributed. Collisions, tidal forces, gravitational waves all "distribute kinetic energy (and momentum) away", eventually turning it into heat.

Weird way to say "if not for those pesky other elements in the system exerting forces on my element, momentum would be conserved for it".


If I'm not wrong, it was held, for example, that a flying spear moves
strongly horizontally and then falls strongly vertically.

Indeed, you are wrong.
Obviously his explanation of movement (in modern terms) is wrong, but goes like this: whatever moves, moves because of something acting upon it. When the arrow was shot, the initial force that shot the arrow, also made the air (around the arrow) to vibrate. That vibration acts upon the arrow so it continues to move. This vibration is passing force through the air to the arrow. But because of power loss, the air loses its power to move the arrow, so the arrow gradually falls to the ground.
In order to understand what exactly is going on, please read https://ikee.lib.auth.gr/record/299287/files/29_Aristotle%20On%20the%20motion%20of%20projectiles.pdf
... a successive transmission of a motive force that gradually diminishes as it is transmitted from a first mover to successive moved movers ...
... αεί ελλάτων η δύναμις του κεινείν εγγίγνηται τω εχομένω (267a8-9) ...
ελλάτων means something that is continuously reduced, becoming smaller.

etymology:
ἐλάττων, -ων, ἔλαττον: αττικός τύπος του ἐλάσσων
(4th-5th bc word for ἐλάσσων)
ελάσσων, -ων, -ον : (λόγιο) μονοτονική γραφή του ἐλάσσων, άλλη μορφή του ελάσσονας, συγκριτικός βαθμός των επιθέτων ολίγος και μικρός. (comparable degree of less and small)

Just to clarify: You are saying that Aristotle never said "first mostly horizontal, then changing to mostly vertical" but instead said the fall is "gradual" (which would align with observation)? I.e., you say the OP's premise is wrong?

Aristotle does not say a thrown object "gradually" falls. He says that the motion only appears continuous but is actually a series of distinct motions. He doesn't seem to mention the fall of the thrown object to the ground at all; he mentions only the air moving it (because the original mover moved the air), and doesn't mention its tendency to return to the ground also moving it. Later authors interpreted this as the OP said: that the motive force pushes the object in a straight line until it ceases, and then the object returns to its natural place, i.e. straight down to the ground.

https://sites.unimi.it/zucchi/NuoviFile/Barnes%20%20-%20Physics.pdf top of page 160 (by the page numbers on the pages)

@causative, (...gradually...) : he does. please read the edit...

@IoannisPaizis Beautiful educative answer, thank you . Have also thanked you in my answer.

@IoannisPaizis The only motion he mentions is the one originally imparted by the person throwing the object. He says this motion diminishes with each successive mover until the motion ceases. He does not mention any simultaneous downward motion; therefore, later authors interpreted this to mean that the downwards motion would happen separately and after the motion from throwing came to a stop. Also he is explicit to say that that the motion is not continuous but only appears so.

@causative, as you probably have guessed, I can read (and understand) the prototype.

@IoannisPaizis You mean you read me the first time? But your edit doesn't reflect that. The point is that though the object gradually comes to a stop from being thrown, he doesn't say it gradually falls.

Can this 'gradually' alternatively be taken to mean each successive portion of flight became shorter and shorter rather than slowly tipping to the vertical from the initial direction of flight whether angled one way or another but perhaps horizontally to match the OP?

@causative, by prototype, I mean the original text.

In that picture 'depicting' canon flight (in distinction from 'ballistic' flight), there are also clouds and birds what were the theories involving their motions? And we also have I suppose rain which might be considered easily as vertical in nature but we all mostly see it as slanting downwards. I'll leave the heavenly points/orbs to the side for the gods to play with.

@civitas, αει means forever, ἐλάττων means something that keeps reducing, so I guess he wants to say : forever/continuesly reducing. The words do not have a direct correspondence with English.

@civitas, This picture is not from Ancient Greece; there are no paintings from that period; at least not in that form.

@IoannisPaizis From the PDF translation I linked, "Now the things in which this motion is produced are things that admit of being sometimes in motion and sometimes at rest, and the motion is not continuous but only appears so"

@Ioannis Paizis, I understand that the picture isn't from a Grecian urn or   palace mural but one answer was using it to depict that the later understanding could be similar to Aristotle's comprehension in that regard. But still that leaves what it was that they thought as to the flight of birds and clouds, how did it differ from spears, arrows and rocks - were clouds carried by winds and birds insects and bats self propelled?

@IoannisPaizis Okay, I had the wrong information. To be specific, I didn't know about the word "gradually". How about physicists from Middle Ages? Did they know about the graduality? Because if they did not, then my question still stands, although with some remarks.

@civitas Since you asked about the motion of birds and raindrops, my answer has links to Aristotle's ideas on the motion of living things and falling objects.

This has been answered better than I ever could.  I'd like to just add - If you take as a premise that Aristotle was describing things that he sees, and perhaps is interpreting them wrong because of ancient lack of knowledge..  Why would you assume that his empirical observations were wrong just because someone interpreted his works that way?
Logically speaking (again, assuming Aristotle wasn't bat-dung crazy), one has to assume that the translation was wrong.  He wasn't predicting a future event such as a feather and a stone falling from a tower - he was describing what he was seeing.
The same goes for the other examples.
The part that can be attributed to bad science (by which I mean lack of scientific knowledge) is his interpretations of his observations..  Not the observations.
Which makes Bertrand Russell's rant from @causative's answer dumb.  I'm not talking about everything Bertrand- just that quote from the answer.
This is more of a lesson in interpretation and context.

Because its untrue. Aristotle got a lot of physics correct. This was the view of Newton who said in his Philosophical Noteboks that "Plato was his friend and Aristotle was his friend". He would not have said this had he thought Aristotelian physics was crazy. He said this because he saw that Aristotle got a lot of important stuff correct.
But Newton also said, "truth was a greater friend", because he could see how he and others could get further alomg that Aristotle did. This has been spectacularly proven by modern physics.
This break with tradition has now turned into a dogma that Aristotle was fundamentally wrong. This is just rubbish.
